# Minima of convex function

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I have a convex function on open interval. We know, that there is no more than one minima, but how do we prove, that there is at least one?

Comment: If you know that there can be only one minimum, perhaps if your function is not too complicated, you can just construct one minimum.  Then you have shown there is at least one.

Comment: Can you show an attempt at it or give a reference book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not always guaranteed. Consider the function $f : (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = x$. Since $f$ is linear, it is also convex. On the other hand, it has no minimum.